# Cant deploy detached expo project with native library

Tags: ios, react-native, testflight, expo, exp

I am trying to deploy on testflight a [detached Expo project](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/detach.html) by uploading it to the appstore via XCode.
But when the downloaded app on my phone tries to use any native library, it crashes with the following error:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating "native function’s name" (code 1)
```

The app works fine in the local environment.

Does anyone know how to do this?. I want to use [Expo](https://expo.io/), but if I can't fix this, I'll have to go with react-native alone.

Comment: Hey there! This is impossible to debug with such little information, and these types of issues aren't a great fit for StackOverflow. If you join the Expo Slack (http://slack.expo.io/) or post about the issue in the forums (http://forums.expo.io/), it will be easier to have a back-and-forth discussion. Thanks!

Comment: Agree with @brentvatne, you could also open an issue on their GitHub https://github.com/expo/expo/issues